# How to make nested jsonb model with django / postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, jsonb

The model I want to make is similar to the youtube api model.

```
{ 
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "snippet": { 
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I tried using `ArrayField` but when I posted a list of fields into the array I kept getting this error:

`"Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."`

This is the model so far

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    burgers = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
        default=None
    )
    beverages = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
        default=None
    )
    extras  = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
        default=None
    )
    fries = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
            size=8,
        ),
        size=8,
        default=None
    )
```

I want to make each item inside the Array to have its own fields for the `name` and `price`.

```
{
   "burgers": [
     0:{
       "name":"Plain patty",
       "price":4
     },
     1:{
       "name":"Cheese buns",
       "price":8
     }
    ]
}
```

How can I make it with `jsonb`?

Comment: [Django **`JSONField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) ?

Comment: `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django`  I did but it said it was depricated.

Comment: @MikiyasAyele: you should import the `JSONField` from `django.db.models`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField

Comment: as Willem mentioned, import the `JSONField` as ***`from django.db.models import JSONField`***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`JSONField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField) to store JSON in a model:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    burgers = models.JSONField()
    beverages = models.JSONField()
    extras = models.JSONField()
    fries = models.JSONField()
```

That being said, storing JSON blobs is not a good idea, especially not when working with relational databases. Usually one defines extra models, and you can work with relations like a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), etc. to define relations. This also makes sure *referential integrity* is guaranteed, as well a *structural integrity*.

Comment: you can also use JSON field validation it and it's really importent https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-schema-a-python-libary-to-validate-your-data-c6d99e06d56a

Comment: @DevangHingu: well one of the problems is that Django's validators do not run when you save model objects. Only when you use model forms. This thus means that it is not guaranteed to validate. A relational database thus *enforces* this. Furthermore it also makes it convenient to refer to the same object: so you can have two or more `Menu`s that have the same `burger`. When using JSON, that is more a problem, since if one of the burgers is updated, then the others with the same data in the JSON blob are not updated. For mongo databases, it is indeed more convenient, and one uses `djongo`.